# Access widgets of a QDockWidget from within the QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt

In my QMainWindow scope I have an instance of a class `AgilentSweeper` which inherits QDockWindow, and initialize and display it with:

```
sweeper = new AgilentSweeper(this);
addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea,sweeper);
```

This class has a Qt Creator-made .ui form which has several widgets in it and the constructor looks like:

```
AgilentSweeper::AgilentSweeper(QWidget *parent) :
    QDockWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::AgilentSweeper)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}
```

where `Ui::AgilentSweeper *ui` is public.

From other functions in the AgilentSweeper scope I can access the AgilentSweeper widgets and do things like `double power = ui->powerSpinBox->value();` normally.  However, I can't figure out how to access the AgilentSweeper widgets from within the scope of the main Ui.  It seems like this should be possible because sweeper is a member   I thought I should be able to do something like `double power = sweeper->ui->powerSpinBox->value();`, but despite messing around with it for a while I can't figure out how to access anything from sweeper's ui.  I can think of several work-arounds, but this seemed like it should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ui Object is defined as private member of AgilentSweeper by default. So normally, you can't access it. 
Some solutions:

1. very bad: declare QMainWindow as friend
2. bad: Change in AgilentSweeper.h private: by public: for the Ui::AgilentSweeper
3. one I would prefer:for each method of your UI-widgets you want to expose, create a public method in AgilentSweeper.h

So you can access the spinbox-value by

```
//in AgilentSweeper.h
double powerSpinBoxValue()
{
    return ui->powerSpinBox->value()
}

//call from outside:
double power = sweeper->powerSpinBoxValue();
```

**EDIT** Explanation for 2

The object `Ui::AgilentSweeper *ui` is defined in AgilentSweeper.h usinf forward declaration. So in a file including AgilentSweeper.h alone, no information is given, how to create an instance of the object and which methods it provides. 
This information is provided by autogenerated file ui_AgilentSweeper.h. so in order to use the way 2, include also ui_AgilentSweeper.h.

Why is this solution bad? It looks so flexible right?

In the first line exposing members as public is bad. A user could delete the instances: e.g. `delete sweeper->ui->powerSpinBox`.

Besides, there is no way to log or lock the access to the member objects.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I actually already did #2 and it's still not working!  Updating the question above.  I will probably do #3 but I'm still curious why this does not work.

Comment: Ah yeah I was not including the autogenerated .h file -- good to know!  I will stick with the 3rd method anyways.